# How to find the combinations (probability) for a,b,c,d,e

Tags: python, algorithm, permutation, probability

How to find the combinations (probability) for a,b,c,d,e    using python/algorithm ?

Given that the length of string is 5 that is minimum 1 & maximum 5.
All the characters can be once .

Example :

```
a
b
c
d
e
ab
ac
abcde
acde 
etc..
```

Comment: Have a look at [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) module. Then come back if you still have questions :)

Comment: I don't see what "probability" you mean, you probably want all permutations of all possible lengths

Comment: @Mighty Pork yes permutations

Comment: If you want the [power set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set), there's an [`itertools` recipe](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import itertools

mystring = 'abcde'
for i in range(1,len(mystring)+1):
    for combo in itertools.combinations(mystring, i):
        print(''.join(combo))
```

Output:

```
a
b
c
d
e
ab
ac
ad
ae
bc
bd
be
cd
ce
de
abc
abd
abe
acd
ace
ade
bcd
bce
bde
cde
abcd
abce
abde
acde
bcde
abcde
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want permutations (as mentioned in comments), try using [itertools.permutations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations):

```
>>> for length in range(1, 6):
...     for permutation in itertools.permutations('abcde', r=length):
...         print permutation
```

Output:

```
()
('a',)
('b',)
('c',)
('d',)
('e',)
('a', 'b')
('a', 'c')
('a', 'd')
('a', 'e')
('b', 'a')
('b', 'c')
('b', 'd')
...
```